# NSUserDefaults doesn't save upon navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I'm developing an app for iPad (IOS7) in Xcode 5 using storyboards. I'm having a strange issue:

I call this method from a button press:

```
-(void)navigateToProjectsPage {
// Save the currently open subject
NSString *detailDescription;
NSString *imageDescription;

// Get the information to be saved
detailDescription = _detailDescriptionTextView.text;
imageDescription = _imageDescriptionTextView.text;

// Create the 2 save keys
NSString *detailDescriptionKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self.detailItem description], @"-detailDescription"];
NSString *imageDescriptionKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self.detailItem description], @"-imageDescription"];

NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[myDefaults setObject:detailDescription forKey:detailDescriptionKey];
[myDefaults setObject:imageDescription forKey:imageDescriptionKey];
[myDefaults synchronize];

// Close this project
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"projectsSegue" sender:nil];

// Show the selectSubjectBanner
_selectSubjectBanner.hidden = NO;
}
```

Which is supposed to save some newly entered data and then modal segue to a new view controller. Whenever I dismiss the new VC and go back to this one and try to load the saved item, it returnes nothing - like if it wasn't saved. However, if I just close my app in the multitasking thing at once, without pressing the button - it saves using the AppDelegate.m method:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
// Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
// If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

// Save what the user entered
NSString *detailDescription;
NSString *imageDescription;

// Get the information to be saved
detailDescription = _detailViewController.detailDescriptionTextView.text;
imageDescription = _detailViewController.imageDescriptionTextView.text;

// Create the 2 save keys
NSString *detailDescriptionKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ([self.detailViewController.detailItem description]), @"-detailDescription"];
NSString *imageDescriptionKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self.detailViewController.detailItem description], @"-imageDescription"];

// Save the data
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:detailDescription forKey:detailDescriptionKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageDescription forKey:imageDescriptionKey];
}
```

Any clue why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probem was that old information remained in the system after entering a new UIViewController when it's supposed to be cleared - wrote this code that fixed it:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        // Clear as we're about to open a new project/exit
    _detailViewController.detailItem = @"";
    selectedSubject = @"";

}
```

You may need to create a BOOL like I did (not in this code snippet) so that it won't interfere with other functions if you're using a MasterDetail Template

Answer (score 1):

`[self.detailItem description]` is unlikely to do what you want. It probably includes the instance pointer of `self.detailItem`, which will change when the detail item changes (and even when you reload with the same detail item) so your key won't match. If anything else changed about the detail item, that could also have an effect.

Keys in user defaults should usually have nice static keys that you can find again.

Too see what you've been adding so far, log `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]` and search for your `-detailDescription` tag.

Also, in your case, using user defaults for this short term style storage (that's what it looks like anyway) probably isn't best. You could be better server by creating and storing (and passing as a property if required) this data in a dictionary.

Comment: the [self.detailItem description] is an item I get when selecting a UITableView cell

Comment: 'Description' is a built in method on `NSObject` - have you tried to replace it?

Comment: A property with a different name, like 'overview'. Same meaning, but it doesn't clash with the existing method.

Comment: but "detailItem" is just a Id declared in the header file of the VC - it's not custom - would a different method work then? The [detailItem description] message comes from the MasterDetailTemplate from Apple - so I kept using that approach

Comment: What do you think? @Wain

Comment: The `description` method in the template is used to display something on screen, you shouldn't use it as a key. You should really have some other unique (and static) identifier that you use as a key.

Comment: What if I create a NSString that is going to hold the same information? Would that be a better approach? @Wain

Comment: What do you mean 'the same information'? The description is usually the class type and pointer. Did you look at what is actually being stored as the key (can you paste it here)?

Comment: Whenever I select something from the UITableView, the information is loaded into the detailItem like this: viewcontroller.detailItem = selectedItem; if I created a new NSString, "hello" - then I would do it like this: viewcontroller.hello = selectedItem; Is that better? Same information as in 'selectedItem'

Comment: The point is not the user of `detailItem`, but of taking the `description` of that item. The description of a string is just the string though, so if your `detailItem` is a string then it doesn't matter (hence my request for you to check what the key is and list it here).

Comment: I may have got something here. Whenever the page goes visible, it somehow sends the message to the saveCurrentSubject() method that saves, and the log says the key is then: (null)-detailDescription @Wain

Comment: I found the culprit! this was called in an unappropiate place: [self saveCurrentSubject]; making it save something that was empty with the wrong string and therefor loading the recently saved empty item. I will rewrite it and come up with a solution

Answer (score 0):

Wain's answer is correct. Description of detailItem will look like `<UIClassName: 0x2ad7b00>`. Also, you asking why your data isn't saved when you navigating. That's because **detailItem** is released when your detail view controller is hidden. When your controller is being shown again, **detailItem** will be allocated again, so it will have different address. Thus, description will be different to.

However, when your application goes background detail view controller stay in memory, and address of the **detailItem** doesn't change.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. When I completely exit the app, slide it up the multitasking page it's still there when i get back. And the detailItem is the value of a UITableView cell (selected one), so that should reload when I tap the item again